# How should I communicate with my server on Heroku if I don't know the port?

Tags: heroku, spark-java

From what I have understood, Heroku assigns a port every time you deploy. I have an android app that is supposed to communicate with my server that I will deploy to Heroku.

But if I don't know the port, how do I make a POST call?
Does that mean Heroku is not suitable for this application?

I am using Java Spark, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dyno internally uses a random port. Only the heroku router should communicate with that port.
You instead need to use the `appname.herokuapp.com` subdomain provided with your app, on port 80 or 443.
The router will then automatically forward the request to one of your dynos in random.

So yes, you can use heroku for your android app. Just make requests on the herokuapp.com subdomain like you would do anywhere else.